# GAS Libraries Fatal Flaw: "Library with identifier FOO is missing (perhaps it was deleted?)"

Tags: google-apps-script

### Question:

Does anyone else experience [this](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3875) problem? And if so, what is the solution or my best course of action?

### Problem Statement:

*Libraries Fatal Flaw: "Library with identifier FOO is missing (perhaps it was deleted?)" + "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again."*

#### Please provide a short description of the issue:

Running any function in my GAS project results in the following error message:

*"Library with identifier FOO is missing (perhaps it was deleted?)"*

If I try to make any changes to my libraries (under the Resources tab) including:

1. updating the library FOO to the latest version,
2. updating a second library (let's call it BAR) to the latest version
3. updating FOO or BAR to any other versions
4. deleting FOO or BAR completely or
5. turning off development mode for FOO or BAR (which are currently in development mode).

In short, any change to the library resources are met with the following error message:

*"We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again."*

- I first observed this error message today.
- I have never seen this problem before since I started this project at least two years ago or more.

#### Please provide a small sample script that reliably reproduces the issue.

*The sample should run as-is or with minimal setup, without external
dependencies.*

```
function test(){Logger.log("A")}
```

#### What steps will reproduce the problem?

1. Delete all code in my project.
2. Copy and paste the above function named "test" into a script file in my project.
3. Attempt to run the above function named "test."
4. After attempting to run "test" and seeing the error message: "Library with identifier FOO is missing (perhaps it was deleted?)," open Resources > Libraries.
5. Attempt to update FOO to it's most recent version. Or make any change to any of the libraries.

#### What is the expected output?

1. After running the function "test" I expect to see that it has successfully completed and the logger reads "A."
2. After trying to update the libraries, I expect to see the new library version in the dialogue box.

#### What do you see instead?

1. I see the error message: "Library with identifier FOO is missing (perhaps it was deleted?)"
2. I see the error message: "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again."

#### Please provide any additional information below.

I have created a new project (let's call it B), copied and pasted all the code from the problem project (let's call it A) to B and successfully integrated the FOO and BAR libraries (latest versions) into B. After doing so, B runs fine without any error. The problem is that all my scriptDB data is still stored in A. Without being able to run any functions from A, I can not export any of my data from A. Otherwise, I would attempt a "messy" workaround such as restarting with B and updating all my (3rd party) calls to A with calls to B, for example.

Comment: I also experience this problem. I created a new file, copied all my code, provided a new name the lib (so instead of 'var a = AAA.myFunction'  I now use 'var a = BBBBBB.myfunction'), changed every name of function, variable and text into BBBBBB. But still I could not run my (short and easy) testscript because of the missing library. I noticed that I deleted an old version (version 1) of the library by accident. Maybe that created the problem. I can imagine that because of the versioning system (keeping track of every code changes) old code reffering to the deleted version-1 causes the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary from comments:

Per @SoftwareTester:

> I also experience this problem. I created a new file, copied all my code, provided a new name the lib (so instead of 'var a = AAA.myFunction' I now use 'var a = BBBBBB.myfunction'), changed every name of function, variable and text into BBBBBB. But still I could not run my (short and easy) testscript because of the missing library. I noticed that I deleted an old version (version 1) of the library by accident. Maybe that created the problem. I can imagine that because of the versioning system (keeping track of every code changes) old code reffering to the deleted version-1 causes the problem.